# $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'] is undefined

Tags: php, file-upload, phpmailer

I am writing a upload file page. Here's the html code:

```
<form action="verify.php" id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file_upload" />
<button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And this is my php code:

```
if ($_FILES['file_upload']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
    return;
  }  
  try{
    $email_add='MY@gmail.com';
    $subject="Driver Verification";
    $mail = $this->emailConfig();      
    $mail->addAddress($email_add, "LALALA");  // Add a recipient
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    echo $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    echo $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $mail->Body    = "This driver requires a verification."
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
    if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Message could not be sent.';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      exit;
    }
    return;     
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    return;
  }
}
```

So when I run the code, it just can echo ['name'] but can't echo ['tmp_name'], and thus there's no attachment in the email.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you catching a `PDOException` in a block not using PDO?

Comment: Could you do a print_r of the file? PD : [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21158995/3281415)  ... Check if you upload a correct image format and size file in your php.ini

Comment: @Machavity,I deleted some code because I am using PDO. But to be read easily, I deleted them.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_FILES);` at the top of your php code and find out what is it receiving.

Comment: @SerCrAsH, print_r prints nothing for ['tmp_name']

Comment: @user3477023 I know it, but I wanna know what is the information of error variable. You are'nt uploading the file.

Comment: Yes! I got it. The error code is 1. Because it exceeds the max size. Thx guys.

Comment: @user3477023 Then, u must change your php.ini variable "upload_max_filesize = 6M" (replace 6M with the maximum number of megabytes per file size.)