# uploading of file does not work in php

Tags: php, upload

I am working on php web application where i upload a file on server from local machine using following code.

```
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         Select file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" value="c:/passwords.txt">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
        </form>
```

**upload.php**

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file =  $target_dir .basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;



        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }


        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
           echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
        echo $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<br>";    
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $target_file)) {       
             echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
          } else {
             echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
           }
        }
```

But above code is not working. I checked uploads folder permission

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 ankit ankit 4096 Aug  2 13:41 uploads
```

which seems to be writable. I changed my project permission using following command

```
  sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/myproject
```

But still i cannot upload the files on server. May i know where i am wrong?

Comment: Do you have an output message with your example?

Comment: Output message: Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: Change the $target_dir path to the full path and see if it works. And also use 775 permissions, instead of 777, for security purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your comments you say that you are getting `error` `1` when you use

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

which is due to

```
 1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
```

So do this

```
upload_max_filesize = 'Size'; // whatever you want
```

[Documentation about $_FILES errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: I am getting "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."

Comment: @user1234 is talking about the error when you `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: I could solve this issue by changing upload_max_filesize = 'Size' parameter.

Comment: Don't forget set 777 permission for your upload/ directory.
For ubuntu ```$sudo chmod -R 777 uploads/```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] // contains the original name of the uploaded file from the user's computer
```

to

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] // tmp_name will contain the temporary file name of the file on the server
```

Documentation for [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). You want to move the upload**ed** file! ;-)

It will help you

Comment: I did it but it does not seem to be working. infact when i print $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] there is no output which means this variable does not exist.

Comment: Try to print_r($_FILES) and check if it is available or not ?

Comment: info:Array
(
    [fileToUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => data.xlsx
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)

Comment: @ankitkumar if there is no tmp_name, it means, it is a broken or corrupt file.

Comment: If it doesn't work with `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)` maybe that you have a problem with **$target_file**! What is the architecture of your folder (or project)?

Comment: My folder is /var/ww/MyProject/uploads where MyProject is places somehere and symlink is created in /var/www

Comment: Does upload.php is in _var/ww/MyProject/_ too?

Answer (score 2):

`move_uploaded_file` expects parameter one to be source, which is `tmp_name`

so change

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $target_file)) {
```

to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
```

Comment: How to fix this isuue if there is no tmp_name or corrupt file?

Comment: i found a similar kind of problem at this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472741/files-field-tmp-name-has-no-value-on-jpg-file-extension, refer the answer given by #staticsan.