# PHP form does not generate tmp_name - multiple upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to proccess multiple upload of images via php. Problem is, that array contains no `tmp_name` parametr for each file so after upload I cant work with images. I have tried it on two different servers with the same behavior.

Images are upload via this input:

```
<input multiple="multiple" id="file_archive[]" name="file_archive[]" size="60" type="file" />
```

generated $_FILES array (without specific tmp_name for each file):

```
 array(1) {
  ["file_archive"]=>;
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>;
    array(2) {
      [0]=>;
      string(14) "logo_white.png"
      [1]=>;
      string(8) "logo.png"
    }
    ["type"]=>;
    array(2) {
      [0]=>;
      string(9) "image/png"
      [1]=>;
      string(9) "image/png"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>;
    string(38) "/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms/back/inside/tmp/"
    ["error"]=>;
    array(2) {
      [0]=>;
      int(0)
      [1]=>;
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>;
    array(2) {
      [0]=>;
      int(24115)
      [1]=>;
      int(38663)
    }
  }
}
```

Form is set as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Script generates no errors.

Thank you for any reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_FILES field 'tmp\_name' has no value on .JPG file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472741/files-field-tmp-name-has-no-value-on-jpg-file-extension)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but, as you can see, my script does not generate any errors so no solution can be found in in linked question.

Comment: Do you can see the files in tmp folder?

Comment: no, when I proccess form with multiple images, no images are in tmp folder. If i proccess form with single image, everything works fine.

Comment: What exactly is that output supposed to be? Neither print_r nor var_dump produce such a format (senseless stuff like `["file_archive"]=>;`) AFAIK.

Comment: it is format of var_dump copied form google chrome console.

Comment: check if the server can write in your tmp folder, also check the apache2 logs

Comment: In my comment above, I wrote that uploading individual images works fine. These are stored in the same tmp folder. I aslo tried it on two different servers with the same effect.