# Check if image has been selected for upload

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have a form were a user can enter text and also upload images.
Saving the values and images works fine. If the user does not select an image, I get the error message that no file has been selected (Error 4).

How can I run the upload image part only if the user selected an image?

I have tried:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name'])){ Upload the Image }

if (!empty($_FILES['files'])){ Upload the Image }

if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name'])) { Upload the Image }

if ($_FILES['files']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { Upload the Image }
```

This the form:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" title="Title" maxlength="10" accept="gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tiff">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_FILES field 'tmp\_name' has no value on .JPG file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472741/files-field-tmp-name-has-no-value-on-jpg-file-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function to check if the user has uploaded any file or not, and then process inputs accordingly, like this:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){
    // user has uploaded a file
}else{
    // user hasn't uploaded anything
}
```

Above solution code is based on your `name` attribute of `input` tag,

```
<input ... name="files[]" ... />
```

If it was `<input ... name="files" ... />` then the `if` condition would be like this:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Use `var_dump($_FILES);` to see the complete array structure.

Comment: If I use if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){...} the code got not called even if I select an image for upload.

Comment: If I run var_dump($_FILES) without selecting a file: array(1) { ["files"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }

Comment: If I run var_dump($_FILES) with selecting a file: array(1) { ["files"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(63) "media.media.56852c99-74ee-4e6e-bf29-b37b0ce6bb46.normalized.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "/home/tmp/phpvyOI7C" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(27933) } } }

Comment: @Beji, as I said in my updated answer; given the current `<input ..>` tag, your `if` block should be like this: `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){ ...`